# Shell script for reading /etc/passwd into SQLite

Tags: sqlite, posix, sh

I want to read 4 columns, namely UID, GID, username and home directory of specific users from `/etc/passwd` into an SQLite database. I found this to create many subprocesses, and I'd like to have some improvement suggestions.

```
#!/bin/sh
db="$PWD/users.db"
users=$(grep -E 'joe|bill|tom' /etc/passwd)
sqlite3 "$db" <<EOF
DROP TABLE Users;
CREATE TABLE Users \
    (UID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, GID INTEGER, Username TEXT, Home TEXT);
EOF
echo "$users" | while IFS= read -r line
do
    sqlite3 "$db" \
        "INSERT INTO Users VALUES ( \
         $(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f3),   \
         $(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f4),   \
        '$(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f1)',  \
        '$(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f6)');"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't create that many subprocesses. Your objective is to prepare a string of `INSERT` statements and feed it to one invocation of `sqlite3`. So drop the whole `while read` block and do the required text manipulations on the queried `passwd` entries before passing them off to `sqlite3`:

```
#!/bin/sh
db='./users.db'
sqlite3 "$db" <<EOF
DROP TABLE Users;
CREATE TABLE Users \
    (UID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, GID INTEGER, Username TEXT, Home TEXT);
$(getent passwd 'joe' 'bill' 'tom' | awk -F':' -v quote="'" -v OFS="', '" \
    '{print "INSERT INTO Users VALUES ("quote $3, $4, $1, $6 quote");"}')
EOF
```

Doing a `grep` on `/etc/passwd` has a few drawbacks: the `passwd` file might not be located in `/etc` (I don't know of any Unix-like OS for which this is true, though), and it won't have the users that are stored in LDAP/NIS, etc. On the other hand, some systems don't have `getent`, so this method is not perfect, either. You might want to fall back to `grep` if `getent` returns a "command not found".